# Richtextbox - on undo?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I need to be able to detect if an "undo" has been triggered, and whether or not it has had an effect on the contents of my `RichTextBox`.

Of I type content into the `RichTextBox` at the minute, and press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, windows seems to handle the undo for me. I want to be able to write code that will get triggered straight after that. I have been looking around and can't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're going to have to [implement that yourself](http://wpftutorial.net/UndoRedo.html). I'm not aware of an event out of the box that will suit your needs.

Comment: @Ken I think that you should promote that up to an answer, I wasn't aware of such a nifty and obvious solution to implementing functionality like that manually.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667302/how-to-get-richtextbox-undo-to-work-better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WINFORM**:

You could exploit the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event and detect if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is pressed:

```
richTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(richTextBox_KeyDown);
```

---

```
private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z){
        //undo detected, do something
    }
}
```

**WPF** :

```
richTextBox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(richTextBox_KeyUp);
```

---

```
void richTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Z) {
        //undo detected, do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from .Net 3.0, there is a simple built-in way to get notified when an undo command (among others) is executed:

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MyClass),
    new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Undo, OnUndo));
```

Just call this line of code in the static constructor (or somewhere else) and add a static method:

```
private static void OnUndo(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: So, would that `MyClass` be the form, or just `RichTextBox` then?

Comment: In my case, it is a class derived from `RichTextBox`, where I added the code that should be handled if an undo was triggered. I'm not sure if it would also work if you try the same directly on the `RichTextBox` (defining the code in some other class).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to [implement that yourself](http://wpftutorial.net/UndoRedo.html). I'm not aware of an event out of the box that will suit your needs.

You might also want to have a look at [Monitored Undo Framework](http://muf.codeplex.com/).
And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33371/Multilevel-Undo-and-Redo-Implementation-in-C-Part) for additional reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you, you want to compare content before and after the `Ctr+Z`.

Then you should do :

In XAML File :

```
<RichTextBox PreviewKeyDown="RichTextBox_PreviewKeyDown" KeyUp="RichTextBox_KeyUp" />
```

In CS File :

```
private void RichTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("After : " + new TextRange(((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentStart, ((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentEnd).Text);
    }
}

private void RichTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before : " + new TextRange(((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentStart, ((RichTextBox)sender).Document.ContentEnd).Text);
    }
}
```

Then, you will see in the output of your application the content of your RichTextBox before the `Ctrl+Z` and the content after.

I've try it and it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

As already described, `CommandBindings` can be used. I prefer binding to each `control` instead of binding to all controls of a specific class. This can be done in the following way:

```
this.richTextBox.CommandBindings.Add(
    new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Undo, this.RichTextBoxUndoEvent));


private void RichTextBoxUndoEvent(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    this.richTextBox.Undo();
}
```